# Two views sharing same controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I have a view which is basically a trimmed down version of the original template. I have trimmed down the view to only the elements I need. I can access the trimmed down view at `'/newclientloanaccount/6'`. Original view is accessible at `'/newclientloanaccount/:clientId'`. Now as I add back elements in the original template these same elements are re-appearing in the trimmed view. In both templates I'm using the same controller. The frontend is in AngularJS 1.0 Bootstrap. I want to know how I can  use state provider in my route configuration so that the trimmed view renders its content correctly.

In my route config I have:

```
(function(weseX) {
    var defineRoutes = function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when('/newclientloanaccount/:clientId', {
            templateUrl: 'views/loans/newloanaccount.html'
          })
          .when('/newclientloanaccount/6', {
              templateUrl: 'views/loans/loancalculator.html'
```

And in both views I have :

```
<div ng-controller="NewLoanAccAppController" class="content-container">
```

Comment: When you load the URL `'/newclientloanaccount/6'`, I suspect your app will load `'/newclientloanaccount/:clientId'` with `clientId` as `6`. Try giving `'/newclientloanaccount/6'` before `'/newclientloanaccount/:clientId'` in `route config`.

Comment: @Safwan I have edited accordingly but im getting an error to the trimmed view now its not populating some dropdowns. My query then is how can i use both route provider and state provider in the same configuration script

Comment: @Safwan I have a working solution. Using the original template i have restricted rendering some elements when  '/newclientloanaccount/6' is accessed.In controller i added scope.currentPath = location.path();  and to restrict a div i added <div ng-show="currentPath=='/newclientloanaccount/6'">.